ReactImageView: Image source "/storage/emulated/0/Download/UAC/forecasts/Salt_Lake/danger.png" doesn't exist. Even though I can verify it does exist
React Native Image
<Image source={{uri: imagePath}}/>

ReactImageView: Image source "/storage/emulated/0/Download/UAC/forecasts/Salt_Lake/danger.png" doesn't exist" even though it does in the android emulator.
Here is how I write the file
 let image = await axios.get(
          `https://PATH TO EXTERNAL SOURCE`,
          {
            params: {
              AccessKey: '',
            },
          },
        );
        let path = `${RNFS.DownloadDirectoryPath}/${center}/forecasts/${region}/`;
        path = path.replace(/ /g, '_');
        console.log(path);

        await RNFS.mkdir(path);

        await RNFS.writeFile(path + '/danger.png', image.data, 'base64');

I verified it by doing adb shell and cd-ing until I found the file I am looking for. These files clearly exists but for some reason the Image cannot find them.

When using a local file path, you need to prefix the path with file://
Here's an example of how you can update your code to include the file:// prefix and use proper URI encoding:
async function downloadAndSaveImage(center, region) {
  try {
    let image = await axios.get(
      `https://PATH TO EXTERNAL SOURCE`,
      {
        params: {
          AccessKey: '',
        },
        responseType: 'arraybuffer',
      }
    );

    let path = `${RNFS.DownloadDirectoryPath}/${center}/forecasts/${region}/`;
    path = path.replace(/ /g, '_');
    console.log(path);

    await RNFS.mkdir(path);

    const imagePath = path + '/danger.png';
    await RNFS.writeFile(imagePath, image.data, 'base64');

    return `file://${imagePath}`;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error downloading or saving the image:', error);
  }
}

Hope it helps to you :)

This was part of the problem. I also needed to convert image.data from an array buffer to a string Buffer with this.
let data = Buffer.from(image.data).toString('base64');
await RNFS.writeFile(path + 'danger.png', data, 'base64');


Glad it helped you :)
